# Binding objects to HTML TextBoxes in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Is this the right way to bind an object to TextBox in ASP.NET? I'm new to it. I want to get and set data to these text boxes from a database?

```
txtusername.Value = objBO_MstrUsers.UserName;
txtPassword.Value = objBO_MstrUsers.UserPassword;
TxtUserlevel.Value = objBO_MstrUsers.UserLevel.ToString();
txtUserPhno.Value = objBO_MstrUsers.UserPhone;
txtUserEmail.Value = objBO_MstrUsers.UserEmail;
```

Comment: read this: https://forums.asp.net/t/1897486.aspx?How+to+bind+model+object+to+textbox+control+input+

Comment: ASP.NET is the overall brand name. Which stack are you using? Webforms, MVC, Razor Pages? ASP.NET Core perhaps?

Comment: You don't "bind" to a textbox in the same way you might in Winforms. This code will set the value of the textbox yes. If you want to get the value back out of the textbox in future (e.g. in a new request after the user has edited it and submitted a form) then you'd need some more code.

Comment: @GlennvanAcker that link is for MVC. The syntax above is very clearly for WebForms. Totally different.

Comment: @ADyson "classic" webforms too. Dynamic Data is closer to what we mean by data binding today but I have no idea if it's still available

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos interesting, I wasn't even aware of Dynamic Data. (I stopped using webforms in favour of MVC and other things, about 7 years ago or more.)

Comment: A webform TextBox does not have a `Value` property, but `Text`. Only a HiddenField does. It looks like OP has not read a single tutorial.

Comment: I'd suggest you to read a couple of MS documentations and tutorials. This one, for ASP.NET Core for example, should give you a full basic application: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/?view=aspnetcore-3.0

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm using webform, three layer Architecture

Comment: @ADyson how do i do that then? Any tutorials or something u can suggest me?

Comment: @VDWWD only asp controls have.text property, I'm using html controls, which doesn't have a.text property while u code.! Maybe it has, i don't know. If u do! Pleas let me know how to!

Comment: @DavidsonSousa I'm using webforms, in three layer architecture, i don't know mvc, have to finish this project fast, doesn't have time to.learn mvc. Was thinking about learning MVC properly after finishing this one

Comment: @Premdasv.m You mean to get the value back? Well it would just be the opposite, basically: `objBO_MstrUsers.UserName = txtusername.Value;` . Obviously it might be slightly different depending on context but that's the basic idea. Nothing complicated! P.S. If you're just learning, I wouldn't bother with WebForms, it's pretty much legacy now (it won't get included in .NET Core, for one thing). You mentioned learning MVC, and that's a good idea, but also look at WebAPI + JS-based frontends  as well. There is lots of good stuff to learn :-)

Comment: @ADyson so basically I'm gonna have to write it both ways, to save a data and get a data! Right?

Comment: @Premdasv.m yes, that's how it works. WebForms was/is pretty cumbersome in that respect. The Dynamic Data thing mentioned earlier can make it easier but that's probably not something you want to start getting your head around if you only have a short time to complete the work.

Comment: @ADyson Thanks bro, and if u don't mind could u lead me to a good tutorial where i can start? And also, please give me link to.learn about the dynamic data thing u told, if i got time I'll do that instead of doing this.

Comment: Just google ASP.NET Dynamic Data for the dynamic data one, there is lots of info

Comment: As for other tutorials, tutorials about what? I mentioned more than one thing to learn! For MVC, you can easily find the official Microsoft one online, that's the best place to start. Same for Web API. Other frontend frameworks such as React, Vue, Angular all have their own tutorials as well. And you can find hundreds of tutorials produced by others. It's impossible to recommend any specific one - they all have different focuses.

Comment: @ADyson also can u help me with one more thing? In this project I've to show a list of data from the db to a table, i was gonna use and Bootstrap table! How can i do that? Also can i add CRUD operation to this table?

Comment: well bootstrap is just a way to change the look and feel of your page. it doesn't affect how you put data onto it. So I'm not sure really what you're asking in relation to that. In WebForms if you want CRUD on a table you're best to use a GridView control. That's usually the quickest way, and again you can find lots of tutorials/information online with a quick search. You can always set bootstrap classes on it to give it a nicer style, too. But if you are short of time, concentrate on getting it working. You can worry about appearance later if you have some time remaining.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to get and set data to these text boxes from a database.

Assuming you have a simple WebForms page such as:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtUsername" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
    </div>
</form>
```

this should work:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        // populate control with database value
        txtUsername.Text = objBO_MstrUsers.UserName;
    }
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // get data from control
    objBO_MstrUsers.UserName = txtUsername.Text;

    // do anything with the data, e.g. store in database
    // ...
}
```